# In Paginated report, 'To date' should be before 'From date' in date Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, powerbi-paginated-reports, paginateddatatable

I have a Paginated report with few filters and a 'From date' and 'To date' filter. The report works fine with all the filter combinations.

Requirement :

1. User should not be able to select 'To date' before 'From date' in the report.
2. User should not be able to select 'From date' after 'To date' in the report.

Any help would be appreciated.

What I tried : I tried adding the function "=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Parameters!FromDate.Value)" in the Default value> specify value> add of the 'End Date' paramter,

In the main report query "AND submittedon BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate" is added in the where condition.

Comment: How are the dates populated in the date parameters? Are they a list of dates from a database query? Are you using the datepicker or a simple list?

Comment: Hello Alan, I actually resolved it.         I got help from the post below, initially I had some challenges, but I resolved that also which is described in it.                                                   
         https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7d3362/ssrs-parameter-validation-using-custom-code/#:~:text=Apply%20validation%20on%20the%20from-date%20and,be%20less%20than%20the%20To%20date.%29&text=Apply%20validation%20on%20the,than%20the%20To%20date.%29&text=on%20the%20from-date%20and,be%20less%20than%20the